# how to borrow mutable reference to different fields of a struct using RefCell::borrowmut

Tags: rust

How do I get mutable references to different fields of a struct stored inside a `RefCell`. What is the harm in getting mutable references to different fields of a struct?

```
use std::cell::{RefCell, RefMut};

#[derive(Default)]
struct A {
    a: i32,
    b: u32,
}

fn main() {
    let mut a_ref_cell: RefCell<A> = Default::default();
    let mut a_obj = a_ref_cell.borrow_mut();
    let a_ref = &mut a_obj.a;
    let b_ref = &mut a_obj.b;
    
    *a_ref = 2;
    *b_ref = 78;
    
    println!("{}, {}", *a_ref, *b_ref);
    println!("Hello, world!");
}
```

Error

```
error[E0499]: cannot borrow `a_obj` as mutable more than once at a time
  --> src/lib.rs:62:22
   |
61 |     let a_ref = &mut a_obj.a;
   |                      ----- first mutable borrow occurs here
62 |     let b_ref = &mut a_obj.b;
   |                      ^^^^^ second mutable borrow occurs here
63 |     
64 |     *a_ref = 2;
   |     ---------- first borrow later used here
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The compiler understands splitting a single borrow into borrows of its fields. However, there's an invisible reason that this doesn't work here:

```rust
let mut a_obj = a_ref_cell.borrow_mut();
let a_ref = &mut a_obj.a;
let b_ref = &mut a_obj.b;
```

`a_obj` is not a mutable reference, but a `std::cell::RefMut` guard object, which releases the borrow when dropped, and until then provides access to the contents by a [`DerefMut`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.DerefMut.html) implementation. Because `DerefMut::deref_mut()` is, in principle, arbitrary Rust code, it gets treated strictly the same as any `fn(&mut self) -> &mut SomethingElse` function — you have to drop the borrow before calling it again.

The simple, local solution to this problem, which works on any kind of dereferenceable thing, is to borrow the contents of the guard once, before you address its fields. (I added type annotations for  explanation; they are not needed.)

```rust
let mut a_obj: RefMut<'_, A> = a_ref_cell.borrow_mut();
let a_obj: &mut A = &mut *a_obj;
```

Now you can borrow fields of `a_obj` separately. This borrow can also be done in the same `let` (which is permitted via [temporary lifetime extension](https://doc.rust-lang.org/beta/reference/destructors.html#temporary-lifetime-extension) applying to the result of the `borrow_mut()` call):

```rust
let a_obj = &mut *a_ref_cell.borrow_mut();
```

Answer (score 5):

There is no harm in it and this is indeed supported with mutable references (it is called *borrow splitting*).

But `RefCell`'s `borrow_mut` doesn't return an ordinary mutable reference: it returns a `RefMut` struct (which works like a mutable reference, but it also has to unlock the `RefCell` on `Drop`).

It uses `DerefMut` to give you a mutable reference, but this requires a borrow to the entire struct and not just the field.

`RefMut` has a function to work around this limitation though:

```
let mut a_obj = a_ref_cell.borrow_mut();
let (mut a_obj, mut b_obj) = RefMut::map_split(|a_ref| (&mut a_ref.a, &mut a_ref.b))
    
*a_obj = 2;
*b_obj = 78;
    
println!("{}, {}", *a_obj, *b_obj);
```